How can possibly undefined objects be handled in a claim?
A method comprising:
a. identifying at least one of a first score and a second score;
b. determining a first winner when the first score is greater than the second score by 10 points;
c. rewarding the first winner;

In this method claim, both the first score and the second score may be undefined, hence step (b) is undefined in either case.
What needs to be achieved is that if the score is undefined, a zero is used in its place.
Question:

What is the standard way to achieve this?


first step - instantiate a first score and a second score to zero, then "update at least one of the first score and the second score"; OR, (a.1) determine a first score based on a first something; (a.2) determine a second score based on a second something. OR (a.1) set a first score to the greater of a first value and zero; (a.2) set a second score to the greater of a second value and zero.
